# Changing org-mode link color

Tags: emacs, org-mode

When I add a link within an `org-mode` heading, is it possible have the link color match the rest of the text in the heading?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19057881/customize-color-of-internal-links-orgmode) question on how to customize the color of org-mode links.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the color of org links always match the text in which they are found, but you can't do that conditionally based on whether they are within headings. If that's good enough for your needs, try:

`M-x customize-face RET org-link RET`

then remove the 'foreground' specification for the face.

Comment: I also had to remove the inherit specification as well before I saw any effect, although the links still do not have the same color as the surrounding text. I've added this to my .emacs: `(custom-set-faces  '(org-link ((t (:underline t)))))`