# Customize color of internal links orgmode

Tags: emacs

It's probably possible, but couldn't find a reference.
How can I define a different color to internal links than external ones through my .emacs file?

Comment: did you have a look a `M-x customize-group RET org-faces` (see http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-appearance.html#sec-1-1)?

Answer (score 3):

The following code will display internal links (those beginning with "`file:`") in turquoise, instead of blue :

```lisp
  (defface org-link-internal
     '((((class color) (background light)) (:foreground "turquoise1" :underline t))
      (((class color) (background dark)) (:foreground "turquoise1" :underline t))
      (t (:underline t)))
  "Face for internal links."
  :group 'org-faces)

  (org-link-set-parameters "file"
               :face 'org-link-internal)
```

**Notes:**

- You'll need `M-x org-mode-restart` to see the changes in your org file ;
- A face can only be set once (with `defface`), so if you want to change an already defined face, either change its name or relaunch Emacs ;
- Already available faces can be seen with `M-x list-faces-display`;
- Available colors for your font can be chosen with `M-x list-colors-display`;
- You can set a different face for other links. For instance I chose to have all links executing elisp code, to be displayed in red (the last link in the below screenshot) :

[image: Screenshot of hyperlinks with different colors]

Answer (score 1):

Ancient question, but since it pops up in searches... Org 9 has a revamped system for defining links, using the `org-link-parameters` variable.  Typically, you modify this through the function ´org-set-link-parameters`, see the org documentation, or the examples here: https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/11/04/New-link-features-in-org-9/